# Delete multiple sharepoint list items programmatically according to some column value

Tags: sharepoint-2007

- I want to delete Document Library items through code.
- Suppose Doc library has one column FolderId.
- I want to delete all items with FolderId 33.

I am trying to delete it through code, but only the first occurence with FolderId 33 is deleted.

When I to try to delete the second occurrence, the following exception occurs:

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.EnsureItemIsValid() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.PrepareItemForUpdate(Guid newGuidOnAdd, SPWeb web, Boolean bMigration, Boolean& bAdd, Boolean& bPublish, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Int32& parentFolderId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update() at ASP._0443e3f9_0806_46ea_98ce_21e2d9f6c224_1904097461.btnDelete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) "
>   Please help me How to delet all items from document library according to folderId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going backwards through the collection:

```
for (int i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    SPListItem item = items[i];
    item.Delete();
}
```